# Convert from ZPL code to IPL code

Tags: zpl, ipl

In my application I have some Zebra printer's and Intermec printer's (PD41). The code is in ZPL language, so my Zebra printer's is working, but my Intermec printer's dont. I need to write this code in IPL language to my Intermec understand the command.
Please, anyone help me!

Answer (score 0):

The two languages are fundamentally different. You will probably end up having to rewrite the label manually if you truly need it in IPL -- there's no easy way to translate between them automatically, per se.

However, many Intermec printers have a feature called **ZSim** which **allows you to print ZPL from your Intermec printer**. I'm not sure if the PD41 supports this, but it's something to check out.